# I found an error while creating a session in python to embed the watson ai features

Tags: machine-learning, ibm-cloud

```
Method failed with status code 404: Resource not found
```

i'm not able to understand why i'm getting Resource not found error. and what does it mean

```
from ibm_watson import AssistantV2, ApiException
from ibm_cloud_sdk_core.authenticators import IAMAuthenticator

authenticator = IAMAuthenticator('api correct')
assistant = AssistantV2(
    version='2023-03-20',
    authenticator=authenticator
)

assistant.set_service_url('used america dallas')

try:
    session = assistant.create_session(
        assistant_id='directly copied and pasted'
    ).get_result()

    session_id = session['session_id']
    response = assistant.message(
        assistant_id='same here',
        session_id=session_id,
        input={
            'message_type': 'text',
            'text': 'Hello, how are you?'
        }
    ).get_result()

    print(response)
except ApiException as ex:
    print("Method failed with status code " + str(ex.code) + ": " + ex.message)
```

i tried to connect it to watson ai through it's api and expected that a response from it but it is always giving me resource error

Answer (score 0):

The error relates to incorrect information put in. You should check the following.

- Apikey is the same as the instance you are calling to.
- That the instance sits in `us-south` (your Dallas comment)
- `assistant_id` is a different value depending on what you are doing.

  - Message, Session and log requests = `environment_id`
  - All other requests use `assistant_id`
  - For classic version always use `assistant_id`

In your sample code you are using `message` so you should use `environment_id`.

To find the environment ID it can be found in the environments section of WA. Click the cog beside the page title.

Alternatively if you click assistant settings in the bottom left you can all settings there.